# Upload file from GWT to php Server

Tags: php, gwt, file-upload

I want to upload a file from a GWT form panel to php server;

```
FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
formPanel.setAction("http://www.digicom.vacau.com/FileUpload.php");
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

In the form panel, I'm placing a file upload widget and submit button. But it is not uploading. Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

You still need to attach a (absolute or vertical)panel to the formPanel and attach a FileUpload widget to that. Don't forget to use formPanel.setWidget(Panel panel)!

Take a look at this code:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html